# Which kit provides the highest yield and purity of extracted DNA from FFPE tissue samples?

Tags: biotechnology, dna-isolation

I'm looking to extract DNA for sequencing from FFPE (Formalin fixed paraffin-embedded) tissue samples. I'd like to use a commercial kit that provides a high yield of good quality DNA.